# how to solve newston.json version error

Tags: c#, android, ios, web-services, xamarin-studio

Actually i am developing my app with xamarin studio for Android and IOS for webService i had included a seperate project in Android and IOS each.

My webService response is in xml form so i converted it in to json by following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument ();
doc.LoadXml (json);
var jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode (doc);
```

using Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5

working in Android.

Shifted to IOS used the same webService c# coding in IOS but it shows me below error:

**Could not load type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicWrapper' from assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.**

[Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr)

[SignalR & WebApi - colliding Newtonsoft.Json references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708912/signalr-webapi-colliding-newtonsoft-json-references)

Tried with the above links but no use if any one have idea please help me out to solve this issue.

Comment: What is the rest of the error. There must be something after what you have posted which describes the rest?

Comment: while working in IOS got the above error none other than that

Answer (score 1):

This is the common error people face with newtonsoft.json while .net project migrations.  I have faced this error too.  I did the below steps.

I use visual studio and I
1) removed the reference from the `.csproj` file and the corresponding dll,
2) uninstalled and installed the package again.

The problem is that nuget package restore updates the package in the dll level but not at the `.csproj` level.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually i am working in xamarin studio where could i find the .csproj file

Comment: tried with the above but remains the same can you please help me out with any other solution.

Comment: Okay.  The reason behind this error is the `dll` version and the version used in the old application are different.  Could you please uninstall and re-install the nuget packages?  In the packages.config could you please check for the correct version of newtonsoft.json.  It causes errors commonly for all on migrations.

Comment: @Manoj- Did you happen to fix the issue?